# What Java library that would auto-generate all the boiler-plate code for calling Web Service?

Tags: web-services

There is wsimport command that generates all the types referenced in WSDL. But this does not do anything with all the remaining boilerplate of calling a web service method, parsing XML into Java objects etc.

Suppose a web service as defined by the service provider WSDL called CustomerService provides an operation getCustomerAddress(String CustomerID) and returns object of type CustomerAddress.
wsimport only generates types such as CustomerAddress. What I am looking for is auto-generated code like:

```
String AppID = "" ;  // autogenerated (if there was such parameter specified in WSDL)
String endpointA = "some end point";
CustomerAddress getCustomerAddress(String customerID) {

// all the bolierplate of actaully calling the webservice, unmarshalling the XML response 
// including error/exception handling etc.


return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like [Spring web services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/), especially if you're already using Spring.

Comment: I could not find how can i use Spring web services to auto-generate the boilerplate code? Can you provide a bit more information?